# Install4j 5.1 - Floating license setup on a headless ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, licensing, headless, install4j, floating

I want to build our app on an Ubuntu server. Our setup programs are created with Install4j 5.1 and integrated in our maven build through the maven-install4j-plugin. The problem I have is that I can't initialize the license information to point to our floating license server (localhost:11862). To initialize the license, I use the following command :

install4jc --license=XXXXXXXXX

The problem is that I don't know the exact syntax to setup the license to a floating server. I've tried --license=localhost:11862 and I've tried to copy-paste my floating license key directly without success.

Where can I find basic instructions on how to setup my floating license infos on a headless system and above all, how to express it to stop receiving "Invalid Syntax Key" when executing install4jc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for using a floating license server is

```
install4jc --license=FLOAT:localhost:11862
```

If you have a Windows Edition license, you currently have to edit

$HOME/.install4j5/config.xml

and change `floatingMultiPlatform="true"` to `floatingMultiPlatform="false"` in that file.

From install4j 5.1.3 on, you will be able to pass the command line option `--windows-edition` instead of editing the config file and the `FLOAT:server` syntax is documented when running `install4jc --help`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Only problem is I now have "The product you are using is not supported by this license server"... I really don't like these useless licensing tricks. Net result is I will switch to an open source alternative... sad,  they have a good product.

Comment: @jgrenon OK, you have a Windows Edition license. Please see my updated answer. This is clearly unacceptable (as well as undocumented). I'll improve this for the next bugfix release.

Comment: @jgrenon I have improved this for the next bugfix release (5.1.3) as detailed in the updated answer.