# Install4j 5.x: Maven-Plugin, Build-Agents and Floating License HowTo

Tags: maven, licensing, install4j

utoday I got the task to integrate a floating license server for install4j to our build process. Therefore I read the README.txt and the following two threads:

[install4jc-specifying-floating-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609968/install4jc-specifying-floating-server) and [floating-license-setup-on-a-headless-ubuntu-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867116/install4j-5-1-floating-license-setup-on-a-headless-ubuntu-server)

Now there are still some questions left. Therefore I will describe our build environment shortly. We are using maven to build our software and installer and startet to test install4j by using the [maven-plugin for install4j](http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html):

1. We installed the install4j application as zip file to our maven repository
2. during maven build we download and extract this file to some target directory
3. until now we installed the demo-license via maven-plugin to the install4j folder
4. during the package-maven-phase we using the maven-plugin to build the installer mediums

That works very nice. Now the company decided to buy a license-bundle including a floating license server. But how to include this to our build process? My suggestion would be the following:

1. install license server to a server reachable over the network
2. modify the config.xml file at the zipped application of the maven-repository and integrate the floating-license-server address **or** set maven-plugin-license property  something like `FLOAT:[server-ip]:11862` at the build configuration?

Is the license-key gotten by ej-technologie only necessary for using the ui? Has anybody some similar build environment and can give me some information how to setup this correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> set maven-plugin-license property something like FLOAT:[server-ip]:11862 at the build configuration?

That would work for the multi-platform edition. If you have the Windows edition, you have to go with:

> modify the config.xml file at the zipped application of the maven-repository and integrate the floating-license-server address

As for:

> Is the license-key gotten by ej-technologie only necessary for using the ui?

The license key is entered in the license server. Both IDE and command line compiler contact the license server. Only the IDE actually checks out a license as long as the IDE is open, the command line compiler just verifies the validity of the license.